# Proving $f$ must be a polynomial no more than $n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic on all $\mathbb{C}$ and that there is a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ and a point $z_0$ such that $|f(z)| \le |p(z)|$ for all $z$ with $|z| \ge |z_0|$. Prove that $f$ must be a polynomial.

Is this a consequence of Lioville's theorem?

Comment: Hint: The hypothesis implies $f(z)$ can be extended as a map    $\mathbf{P}^1\to \mathbf{P}^1$ by fixing infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is analytic on all $\mathbb{C}$, we know by the maximum modulus principal that $f = const$ or takes it's maximum modulus on the boundary of $|z| \leq |z_0|$. This implies that the condition we have will become:

$$ |f(z) | \leq |p(z)|, \quad |z| \geq |z_0| \implies |f(z) | \leq |p(z)| \quad ,\forall z \in \mathbb{C}  \iff  |g(z) |  \ =\frac{ |f(z) |}{|p(z)| } \leq 1 $$

Therefore, by Lioville's Theorem, we know $g(z) = const$. This of course implies that (for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$):

$$ \lambda = g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{p(z)} \iff f(z) = \lambda p(z) $$

Since $p(z)$ is a polynomial, $f(z)$ is aswell.

Comment: This would imply $g(z)$ is constant?

Comment: That's what you'd like! In your case we don't have this inequality for all of $\mathbb{C}$ (only for $|z| \geq |z_0|)$, is there anyway we can compensate for this?

Comment: I'm having trouble with what that means $|z| \ge |z_0|$

Comment: @User69127: Consider a circle of radius > $|z_0|$

Comment: I still can't connect the dots :-(

Comment: Do you know of Weirstrass Factorization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem you can use it inside of the disk $|z|<|z_0|$, and use Jeb's idea outside of that disk.

Comment: @Contactoid No I never covered Weirstrass Factorization. I only have Lioville's theorem here

Comment: I've changed my hint to a sloppy solution.